# Is it possible to change title icon of the dialog in InstallShield?

Tags: icons, windows-installer, installshield

Is it possible to change an icon that you can see on every dialog bar in InstallShield?

I know how to change setup.exe icon in InstallShield, I also know how to change icon to display with my application in Add or Remove Programs. But what about a default "computer" icon that you can see together with Dialog title in a top-left corner of each dialog?

I'm using InstallShield 2013 Professional, Basic MSI project type.

Comment: I believe this comes from Windows itself as part of the Windows Installer engine resources. It still might be possible to replace, but I guess it would require some serious hacking in the MSI.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the icon shown in the title bar for a Basic MSI project. However if you use an Advanced UI project to install the MSI, the UI that InstallShield provides does support selecting a custom icon. It's not necessarily trivial to change to the Advanced UI project type, and requires a .exe bootstrap, so the option may or may not be right for your case.